# Проблема с AngularJS-Slider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Использую следующую директиву [AngularJS slider directive](http://angular-slider.github.io/angularjs-slider/).
Сделал вот такую штуку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*HTML:*

```
<rzslider class="custom-slider" rz-slider-model="slider_val.minValue"
         rz-slider-high="slider_val.maxValue"
         rz-slider-options="slider_val.options"></rzslider>
```

*JS:*

```
$scope.slider_val = {
        minValue: 1,
        maxValue: 10,
        options: {
            floor: -10,
            step: 1,
            сeil:15,
            noSwitching: true,
            autoHideLimitLabels:true,
            enforceStep:false,
            precision:0
        }
    };
```

**Мои ожидания**: линия от -10, до 15, выбран промежуток от 1 до 10.
**По факту**: линия от -10, до 10, выбран промежуток от 1 до 10.

[Вот пример](https://jsfiddle.net/954eve2L/2649/).

---

Что мне сделать, чтобы было так, как я хочу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это очепятка, Вы используете [кириллическую "с"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0441/index.htm) вместо [латинской "c"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0063/index.htm) в ключе `ceil`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!)